# Helm How do I list or query the environment variables that are set for Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have search the Helm documentation and this forum as well as others and see no way to print out or list the environment variables that Helm uses... In the docs it states that you can set env vars with override flags but I see no instructions to list what (if any) environmental vars Helm uses ...

I was thinking something like printenv or echo ${HELM_HOME} or echo $(HELM_HOME)...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The support for environment variables was initially discussed in [helm issue 944](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/944), and implemented in [PR 982](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/pull/982) for Helm 2.0 in July 2016.

[As documented](https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/4b6fbbb67f32d10d23696f2a51b36684579fa763/cmd/helm/install.go#L41-L52)

> To override values in a chart, use either the '`--values`' flag and pass in a file
>   or use the '`--set`' flag and pass configuration from the command line.
>
> ```
> $ helm install -f myvalues.yaml redis
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> $ helm install --set name=prod redis
> ```
>
> To check the generated manifests of a release without installing the chart,
>   the '`--debug`' and '`--dry-run`' flags can be combined.
>   This will still require a round-trip to the Tiller server.

The last part should at least allow you to check the generated manifests of a release, which should include environment variables.

[`install.go`](https://github.com/technosophos/k8s-helm/blob/4b6fbbb67f32d10d23696f2a51b36684579fa763/cmd/helm/install.go#L150-L169) offers a method `(v *values) Set(data string)`: a setter... but no getter, beside a `String()` method.